# WAMPP server (Computer software)

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, visual-studio, visual-c++

I downloaded "WAMPP server 64bit" for my windows 8.1 pro (yet to activate), lenovo  laptop. But during its installation, it prompted a message like: "api ms win crt runtime... .dll is missing" For that I downloaded Visual C++ 2015 redist even that is not installing properly, do I need visual studio for installing visual C++ 2015?? Any help?

Comment: "do I need visual studio for installing visual C++ 2015?" - No;  Visual Studio isn't required to install VC++ 2015 redistributable.  You will have to provide specifics on the reason it isn't installing properly.

Answer (score 0):

The first instruction shows about the dependencies. So uninstall first, during reinstall see the instructions properly and download the required packages from given link. Links and dependencies name will be there. Hope it will work